# Exact sequences free abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

I have an exact sequence ending with
\begin{equation*}
\cdots \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{f_1} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{f_2} \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{f_3} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow (0)
\end{equation*}

Can I say that $Im(f_1) = (0)$? My argument goes like this: we know $f_3$ is surjective, so
since $Ker(f_3) = Im(f_2)$,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / Im(f_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation*}
But $Im(f_2)$ is a subgroup of a free abelian group of rank $2$, so it is itself a free abelian group, and the rank must be $1$ because of this quotient relation, hence $Im(f_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Then, we obtain, since $Ker(f_2) = Im(f_1)$,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{Z} / Im(f_1) \cong Im(f_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation*}

So it seems trivial to me that must have $Im(f_1) = (0)$. Is that correct or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know, I deleted my comment.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, and there doesn't seem to be anything strictly wrong with your steps, but you seem to be throwing around isomorphisms a little too casually. You should keep in mind that isomorphic objects can't always be treated as the same. For example, if you have a nonzero map $f : \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, then $Im(f)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{Z}/Im(f)$ doesn't have to be 0. (take for instance $f(1) = 2$)

Comment: If $f_2$ was not injective then the image of $f_2$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for some $n$.  But there is no such subgroup of $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ unless $n=1$, but if $n=1$ then $f_3$ is injective.

Comment: I know, I think the only step that can cause a little of thinking is the one with $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / Im(f_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ then $Im(f_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. I was trying to thing about someting like you said, for example the group $2\mathbb{Z}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, but its quotient with $\mathbb{Z}$ is finite. But in my question I know the quotients have rank 1, so I think that's why mu conclusion is correct.

Comment: The correct argument I think it is that quotient of free abelian groups of the same rank need not be free: in fact they are of rank 0, and they are a product of cyclic groups, am I right?

Comment: NB. Can I apply the same argument by replacing $ \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus n}$ and the first $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus (n-1)}$? Is the conclusion still correct?

Comment: @Klaramun The quotient of any free abelian group can fail to be free. Take $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\langle (2,0)\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$.